# Restarting code in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python, this is my first language to try. I am starting to get the hang of it a little bit, just need some help. I am making a simple calculator with the code below, and I was wondering how to restart my code from the beginning (You can see my try at the bottom).

```
import math
import time

def game():
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

    def subtract(x, y):
        return x - y

    def multiply(x, y):
        return x * y

    def divide(x, y):
        return x / y

    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("1. Add")
    print("2. Subtract")
    print("3. Multiply")
    print("4. Divide")
    a = int(input("Please choose 1, 2, 3, or 4."))

    def choice():
        if a == 1:
            print("You are now adding.")
        elif a == 2:
            print("You are now subtracting.")
        elif a == 3:
            print("You are now multiplying.")
        elif a == 4:
            print("You are now dividing.")
    choice()

    first_num = int(input("What is the first number you want to use?"))
    time.sleep(2)
    second_num = int(input("What is the second number you want to use?"))
    time.sleep(2)

    def execute():
        if a == 1:
            print(first_num, "+", second_num, "=", add(first_num,second_num))
        elif a == 2:
            print(first_num, "-", second_num, "=", subtract(first_num,second_num))
        elif a == 3:
            print(first_num, "x", second_num, "=", multiply(first_num,second_num))
        elif a == 4:
            print(first_num, "/", second_num, "=", divide(first_num,second_num))
    execute()

game()

def playagain():
    input("Would you like to calculate another problem? Yes or No")

playagain()

while playagain == "Yes":
    game()
```

Comment: you never assign the return value of `input()` anywhere. You're comparing a function to a string, that will never return True.

Comment: `while playagain() == "Yes":` and `return input("...")`

Comment: Please fix your mistakes (`P.S. Code is messed up, starts with import math and ends with the statement below. Sorry! New to this`)

Comment: I think you are miss understanding when and where to use functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `loop` to do that, for example:

```
play_again = True
while play_again:
    # your code goes here
    inp = input("Would you like to calculate another problem? Yes or No")
    play_again = inp.lower() == 'yes'
```

this will change the `play_again` to `False` if the input isn't yes

Comment: `while play_again` means `while play_again` equals `True`; it will keep running the loop forever until `play_again` is `False` or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to a workable solution:

```
def playagain():
    return input("Would you like to calculate another problem? Yes or No")

while playagain() == "Yes":
    game()
```

You need to `return` the value that they type from input, then `playagain()` will ask them and insert that value in it's place, so it is then compared to "Yes".

There is nothing particularly wrong with your current method.

Comment: Thanks this worked! It was the first one that I tried and the only problem was raw_input is supposed to be just input. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're really close with the logic at the end. No need for a while statement, just an if statement.

```
playagain = input("Would you like to calculate another problem? Yes or No")
if playagain == "Yes":
    game()
```

If you want to keep asking after a problem is solved, then you can do an if else inside the game function instead of outside, so it will continue to ask for the playagain variable after the question is asked.

```
playagain = raw_input("Would you like to calculate another problem? Yes or No")
if playagain == "Yes":
    game()
else:
    return
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I'm hard pressed to see why one should replace a `while` loop with a recursive call when we're not using a recursive function.

Comment: Thanks! Good to be here. I work with recursive functions constantly in my job, so I guess I'm living the old adage that when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail.